# Core Plot: number of major x intervals

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, core-plot

Using core plot framework I have an `XYScatter Plot`. Everything works fin, but my x-axis has 3 major tick marks. Full scale is 10 so this is making my major ticks come out on the 1/3. Very strange. I have tried different combinations of:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet               = (CPTXYAxisSet *)plot.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x                        = axisSet.xAxis;

x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks       = 4;
x.majorIntervalLength               = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:35.0] decimalValue];
x.labelingPolicy                    = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
```

... but can not seem to get what I would like - a plot that has major ticks divisible by 2 or  or 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving `preferredNumberOfMajorTicks` at the default of zero (0). If the plot range has length 10, this should give you ticks every two units apart. The `majorIntervalLength` property has no effect on the automatic labeling policy.